# Installing android emulator for react-native app

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile, android-virtual-device

I am running react native and i want to install android command line tools but it did not come with andro/id emulator, so how do i download and run android emulator with the android command line tools??

Thank you in advance.

This is the error i get if i run the app

C:\Users\Moses Henen\Documents\demo\rn\AwesomeProject>npm run android

> AwesomeProject@0.0.1 android
> react-native run-android

info Starting JS server...

info ?? Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correct
ly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: htt
ps://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.
md#doctor

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Downloading from https://service
s.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0.1-all.zip failed: timeout (10000ms)